# Who is the base class of NSObject in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsobject, base-class

I heard `NSObject` is the main parent class where all classes are derived. But my question is there any class existing where `NSObject` class is being derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSObject` is the primary, but not only, *root class* of Cocoa. A root class does not have a base class, it is the root of class hierarchy.

Another Cocoa root class is `NSProxy`.

Note: The above are all root classes of Cocoa, Apple's framework, the Objective-C language itself does not define any root classes at all - this differs from languages like Java and C# where there is a language defined root class or classes.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple Documentation Says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/)

> NSObject is the **root class** of most Objective-C class hierarchies. Through NSObject, objects inherit a basic interface to the runtime system and the ability to behave as Objective-C objects.

Also [Root Class Says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/RootClass.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH46)

> **A root class inherits from no other class** and defines an interface and behavior common to all objects in the hierarchy below it. All objects in that hierarchy ultimately inherit from the root class. **A root class is sometimes referred to as a base class.**

Answer (score 0):

NSObject and NSProxy are two root classes in Cocoa. NSProxy is rarely used in Cocoa applications and never in Cocoa Touch applications.